# HTML card not displaying properly

Tags: html, css

Trying to copy www.codepen.io/mauriceconchis/pen/YWBxAg, but getting this: [image: screenshot]

style.css is in the same directory as the HTML file.

Comment: You should start here before posting any questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ZimSystem thanks, can you also assist with this? quite stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably trying to use SCSS as CSS, try using the CSS below in the `style.css` file instead. You will also need to ensure you are linking to the CSS file correctly in the `<head>` section, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" url="style.css">
```

I have included the correct HTML below as well.

You can test this code by running the snippet.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #034378, #2d4e68);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.row {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 1.7rem;
  width: 50%;
}
.card .menu-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.card .menu-content::before, .card .menu-content::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
.card .menu-content::after {
  clear: both;
}
.card .menu-content li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.card .menu-content a {
  color: #fff;
}
.card .menu-content span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
.card .wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 540px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 15px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.card .wrapper:hover .data {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.card .data {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(calc(70px + 1em));
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}
.card .data .content {
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.card .author {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.card .title {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.card .text {
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0;
}
.card input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}
.card input[type='checkbox']:checked + .menu-content {
  transform: translateY(-60px);
}

.example-1 .wrapper {
  background: url(https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1463415268136-e52a5af54519) center/cover no-repeat;
}
.example-1 .date {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #77d7b9;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.8em;
}
.example-1 .date span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.example-1 .date .day {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
}
.example-1 .date .month {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.example-1 .date .month,
.example-1 .date .year {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.example-1 .content {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.example-1 .title a {
  color: gray;
}
.example-1 .menu-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.example-1 .menu-button span {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: gray;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.example-1 .menu-button span::after, .example-1 .menu-button span::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: currentColor;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.example-1 .menu-button span::before {
  left: -10px;
}
.example-1 .menu-button span::after {
  right: -10px;
}
.example-1 .menu-content {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.example-1 .menu-content li {
  width: 33.333333%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #77d7b9;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
}
.example-1 .menu-content a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 24px;
}
.example-1 .menu-content span {
  top: -10px;
}

.example-2 .wrapper {
  background: url(https://tvseriescritic.files.wordpress.com/2016/10/stranger-things-bicycle-lights-children.jpg) center/cover no-repeat;
}
.example-2 .wrapper:hover .menu-content span {
  transform: translate(-50%, -10px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.example-2 .header {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
}
.example-2 .header::before, .example-2 .header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
.example-2 .header::after {
  clear: both;
}
.example-2 .header .date {
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.example-2 .menu-content {
  float: right;
}
.example-2 .menu-content li {
  margin: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.example-2 .menu-content span {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.example-2 .data {
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(calc(70px + 4em));
}
.example-2 .title a {
  color: #fff;
}
.example-2 .button {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 2em auto 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.example-2 .button::after {
  content: '\2192';
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.example-2 .button:hover::after {
  transform: translate(5px, -50%);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="example-1 card">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="date">
            <span class="day">12</span>
            <span class="month">Aug</span>
            <span class="year">2016</span>
          </div>
          <div class="data">
            <div class="content">
              <span class="author">Jane Doe</span>
              <h1 class="title"><a href="#">Everything You Need to Know About Gold Medals</a></h1>
              <p class="text">Olympic gold medals contain only about 1.34 percent gold, with the rest composed of sterling silver.</p>
              <label for="show-menu" class="menu-button"><span></span></label>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" />
            <ul class="menu-content">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-heart-o"><span>47</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-comment-o"><span>8</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="example-2 card">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="header">
            <div class="date">
              <span class="day">12</span>
              <span class="month">Aug</span>
              <span class="year">2016</span>
            </div>
            <ul class="menu-content">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-heart-o"><span>18</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-comment-o"><span>3</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="data">
            <div class="content">
              <span class="author">Jane Doe</span>
              <h1 class="title"><a href="#">Stranger Things: The sound of the Upside Down</a></h1>
              <p class="text">The antsy bingers of Netflix will eagerly anticipate the digital release of the Survive soundtrack, out today.</p>
              <a href="#" class="button">Read more</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I have tested this HTML and CSS locally as well and it works perfectly.
[image]

Comment: you are amazing!